# Здравствуйте! В callback_query_handler() aiogram передается message.text из message_handler() и сохраняется

Tags: python, aiogram

В callback_query_handler() aiogram передается message.text из message_handler() и сохраняется, при дальнейшем использовании бота и ввода нового message в callback_query_handler() message.text не меняется и остается тот, который введен первым, как это исправить? Спасибо

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def term_send_it(message: types.Message):
    if(message.text == "❓ Come usare"):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привеет.. Спасибо что читаешь статью!)")
    else:
        await message.answer(wikipedia.summary(message.text, sentences=2))
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Perfeziona richiesta", callback_data='know_it')
        button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"{(message.text).capitalize()} su altre risorse", callback_data='more_it')
        markup.row(button4, button5)
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Non sei soddisfatto della risposta?".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

        @dp.callback_query_handler()
        async def lang_it(call: types.CallbackQuery):
            if call.data == "more_it":
                await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                button6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"{(message.text).capitalize()} su Wikipedia", url=wikipedia.page(message.text).url)
                markup.add(button6)
                button7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"{(message.text).capitalize()} su Youtube", url=f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={message.text}&sp=CAA%253D")
                markup.add(button7)
                button8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"{(message.text).capitalize()} su Shutterstock", url=f"https://www.shutterstock.com/ru/search/{message.text}")
                markup.add(button8)
                await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="⬇️Scegli la risorsa richiesta⬇️".format(call.message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
            elif call.data == "know_it":
                await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
                await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text=f"Immettere una delle opzioni - {str(wikipedia.search(message.text))[ 1 : - 1 ]}")
```

Comment: Не вижу у вас передачи переменной, захват вижу, передачи - не вижу.

Comment: Я новичок, не могли бы помочь как это сделать, спасибо

Comment: Сделать что? у вас в коде - нет того о чем вы заявляете, переменные передаются в функцию в качестве аргументов!, у вас такого нет, у вас отсутствуют аргументы у функции callback_query_handler, значит вы ничего не передаете, а делаете подобие захвата, и оно именно так как вы описали и работает, берется первое доступное значение и потом используется постоянно. https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html

Comment: Перепробовал все что позволяли знания, ничего не получается, буду очень благодарен, если подскажите, как передать аргумент и какой в этом конкретном случае, спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте call.message.edit_text(текст)

Comment: Cпасибо за совет, но не помогло